# Save dynamic content from jquery to file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code to create a div inside a div with id container when you press a button

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#add").click(function(){
      $('#container').append( $('<div>test</div>').addClass('div-color') );
  });

});
```

html

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

How can I save the container div and the dynamically generated data in a file on the server? For example, if the user clicks the button twice, I want to save the following in a test.html file on the server (container div and everything that's in it).

```
<div id="container">
<div class="div-color">test</div>
<div class="div-color">test</div>
</div>
```

Guess it is not possible with javascript and if so, PHP is OK to use.

Comment: Did tried a search ? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15344624/1267304) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16873549/1267304).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'save.php',
  data: { content: $('#container').html() }
});
```

Then receive POST data and save it to file with php.